# How to call ArrayList items one by one from Another Activity?

Tags: android, listview

I am new to Android development. I used listview with edittext in an activity and I want to call edited listview items one by one in order in another activity. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say you want to "call edited listview items one by one in order in another activity"

In general, you should not use `ListView`. Instead you should use `RecyclerView` which is much more performant and modern

Comment: What have you done so far? What are your attempts? Do you have code that you can share, especially a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Answer (score 0):

How can I use listview items added by users for another activitiy. For example in my first activity, users add names as much as they want, in second activity, I should display first item added in textview then second item added in textview then third etc. Unfortunately, there is no code. I ll just start. Thanks a lot